# Android Google Map v2 in Navigation Drawer in onCreateView()

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm having an issue with my Android app. I'm using navigation drawer with onCreateView() inside of a PlaceholderFragment like this:

```
// Google Map
private GoogleMap map;
private final LatLng LOCATION_DEPAUW = new LatLng(39.640343, -86.860687);

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

/**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = null;
```

...

```
else if(mTitle.equals("Map")){
            Log.d("Map", "Worked");
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.google_map, container, false);

            try {                       

                    if (map == null) {
                        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                        map = fm.getMap();
                    }


                    // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
                    try {
                        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
                    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_DEPAUW, 15);
                    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
                    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
                    map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                    map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
                    map.animateCamera(update);

                    /*
                     * for different colors:
                     * googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng( 65.07213,-2.109375)).title("This is my title").snippet("and snippet").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
                     * 
                     * .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE) is the key. change the HUE_ORANGE to anything that is available
                     * 
                     */

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
 }
```

I have already imported everything correctly and the map initializes correctly on the first view. The problem is when I navigate to another fragment and then go back to this map fragment, my app crashes. I've tried to use an eclipse emulator but couldnt get it configured correctly. Does anyone know a way to handle the life cycle of a map inside a placeholderfragment? Thanks!

Comment: can u post your logcat?

Comment: Can't. Couldn't get the emulator to use GPS. I have tried to get my phone to use developer mode but it wont work. Just wondered if anyone knew about this

Answer (score 1):

So after a lot of research, I found out someone manage to handle this well.

Check out this github repository:

https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551

MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap map;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, container, false);

    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    map = mapView.getMap();
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}
```

initially though, I had issues cause I had multiple fragments to switch between, so i did this in mine:

```
public void onResume() {        

        try{    
            super.onResume();
            mapView.onResume();
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                Log.d("onResume", "NullPointerException: " + e);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        try{
            super.onDestroy();
            mapView.onDestroy();
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            Log.d("onDestroy", "NullPointerException: " + e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        try{
            super.onLowMemory();
            mapView.onLowMemory();
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            Log.d("onLowMemory", "NullPointerException: " + e);
        }
    }
```